# Synonym [knobs] to [doorknob]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

- [knobs](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knobs) - 11 questions
- [doorknob](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doorknob) - 51 questions

There's only one usage of [knobs] with [cabinets](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cabinets). I propose we make [cabinet-knobs] for that. The other usages can have the tag removed

Comment: The Stack Exchange software has a periodic job that removes tags that have a single usage, so the [cabinet-knobs] tag might not last long. Counter proposal: [cabinet-hardware] which could apply to knobs, hinges, sliders, pull-out racks, lazy susans, etc.

Comment: I think that's a good idea